# Show that for $(X,d)$ a metric space, $U= \{x \in X: d(x, C) \leq d(p, C)\}$ is a closed set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $C$ be a closed set in $X$. Define  $$d(C, x) := \inf \{d(c, x): c\in C \}$$ for all $x \in X$. Fix a point $p \in X$. Show $U= \{x \in X: d(x, C)\leq d(p, C)\}$ is a closed set in X.

I started with $X= ∪{cl(B_{d(p,C)}(x):x∈C)}$, but I'm not sure if $∪{cl(B_{d(p,C)}(x):x∈C)}=cl(∪{B_{d(p,C)}(x):x∈C})$ or not.

Comment: When asking a question, it is always a good idea to include your thoughts on the question. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Along the lines of iHubble's comment, please see this [link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for question guidelines.

Comment: Consider $d(x,C) - d(p,C)$, use the continuity of $d$.

Comment: I started with X= $\cup${cl(B$_{d(p,C)}(x):x \in C$)}, but I'm not sure if $\cup${cl(B$_{d(p,C)}(x):x \in C$)}=cl($\cup${B$_{d(p,C)}(x): x\in C$}) or not

Comment: Place your thoughts in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is a continuous function then $\{x\colon f(x) \le c\}$ is a closed set.

You need to prove that $x\mapsto d(x,C)$ is continuous... this is an easy task, actually you can prove that
$$
 \lvert d(x,C) - d(y,C)\rvert \le d(x,y).
$$

Comment: Preimage of closed set is closed. Thank you!